# Load two blocks of javascript in template

Tags: templates, flask, django-templates, jinja2

I need to include a specific js in top of document. If I try to define another `block scripts` I will get an error  `block "defined twice"`. The easy way is just load this js in `block styles`, but it not seems good in terms of strucutre.

My question is how can I load two blocks of javascript files. One at top and another at bottom.

```
{% block styles %}
{{super()}}
<!--load CSS-->
{% endblock %}

page content

{% block scripts %}
{{super()}}
<!--load js-->
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By chance are you trying to add two blocks named `scripts`?

To make this work, add another block with a different name. E.g.,

```
{% block extrascripts %}
<!-- load your extra scripts, if any, here -->
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: We can use any name? Or this is documented somewhere in jinja?

Comment: You can use any name. 'style' and 'scripts' are conventions. See http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/templates/#template-inheritance